# get link to iCloud file from finder without having to go to iCloud website?

Tags: finder, icloud, file

Is it possible to get a remote link to a file via finder? I want to be able to share my screenshots really quickly which are now saved to an iCloud folder. Thanks, D.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible as of Yosemite 10.10.5. The sharing menu would be a sensible place for this, but it doesn't have an option to send or copy a link to the file, choosing Mail or Messages will attach the full file:

[image: Current share options]

Personally I use [Dragshare](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dragshare/id707059884?ls=1&mt=12) to quickly get a remote link to a file, or if you save your files to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) you can just alt-click and choose Share Dropbox Link.

Comment: Thanks but really want this to be an apple solution. iCloud is such a major part of apple devices i don't want to pay for the space required for dropbox. The free space i have is already nearly full. As a short term solution i've created an applescript that adds images in a folder to a Photos album. I'll then have to create a shared album per project.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to get an iCloud link natively with macOS High Sierra:

1. Select a file in one of your iCloud folders (Desktop, Documents, etc.)
2. Choose Add People from the Share menu
3. Click the Copy Link button
4. Change "Who can access" to "Anyone with the link" under "Share Options" section

It'll look something like this:

[image: Current share options]

Comment: Apparently this feature was removed sometime after High Sierra. It is not present  on Ventura and it is very frustrating.

Comment: The process has changed again but I believe it should be possible, here's Apple's documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/mac-help/mchl91854a7a/mac

Comment: @Andrew Contrary to the Apple documentation the Copy Link menu item is not available in OSX 12 Monterey. Disappointment.